# params to find by name instead of id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I want the url structure to be 'actors/joe-blogs' instead of 'actors/1' but with the id out of the url I cant get params to find by name instead of find by id.

I have the following route

```
get 'actors/:name' => 'actors#show'
```

actors table

```
| id |   name    |
------------------
| 1  | Joe Blogs |
```

The url /actors/joe-blogs works fine but finding params by name instead of id doesn't work.

actors controller:

```
    def show
       @actor = Actor.find(params[:name])
    end
```

Finding by params name looks for the actor with `{"name"=>"joe-blogs"}`  instead of looking for the actor with `{"name"=>"Joe Blogs"}`

How can I get params to work so it grabs `{"name"=>"Joe Blogs"}`? without the '-' in-between the name?

Comment: does this work ? 
@actor = Actor.find_by(name: params["name"])

Comment: I think you should use https://github.com/norman/friendly_id, it will full fill all your need

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `find_by` instead of `find`.

```
def show
  @actor = Actor.find_by(name: params[:name])
end
```

Comment: When i change it to that and try <%= @actor.name %> on the show.html.erb page i get a `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass` error.

Comment: @user3234020 Can you post the params that are coming?

Comment: @user3234020 It appears the keys in hash you mentioned are strings, not symbols. does params["name"] work ?

Comment: Yes they are strings. in both of your answers the parameter is still {"name"=>"one-piece"}

Comment: Ok looking into it the draper gem or friendly_id gem will help with my url issue. You helped me figure out the paras problem so ill mark this as the answer

Answer (score 0):

You'll be best using [`friendly_id`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id), which will fix all of this functionality for you. You won't have to change anything except adding a `slug` column to your datatable:

```
#Gemfile
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1'

$ rails generate friendly_id
$ rails generate scaffold actor name:string slug:string:uniq
$ rake db:migrate

#app/models/actor.rb
class Actor < ActiveRecord::Base
   extend FriendlyID
   friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]
end

$ rails c
$ Actor.find_each(&:save)
```

This should set up all your `Author` records to have a `slug`, which will allow you to use the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :actors #-> no change required

#app/controllers/actors_controller.rb
class AuthorsController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @author = Actor.find params[:id] #-> will automatically populate with slug
   end
end
```